# Pandas equals gives False result even it should be True

Tags: pandas

Let me generate a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,1]])
```

then I compare

```
df[0].equals(df[1].sort_values())
```

this gives False.

However, both `d[0]` and `df[1].sort_values()` gives the same output

```
0    1
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Why `equals` gives False? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is different order of index values, so if create same e.g. here by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=true` it working like you expected:

```
a = df[0].equals(df[1].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True))
print (a)
True
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[0])
0    1
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print (df[1].sort_values())
1    1
0    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64

print (df[1].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True))
0    1
1    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So I guess it is better to use `np.array_equal` for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly access Series values:

```
np.equal(df[0].values, df[1].sort_values().values)
array([ True,  True])

np.equal(df[0].values, df[1].sort_values().values).all()
True

np.array_equal(df[0], df[1].sort_values())
True
```

As time perfomance is concerned, second and third approaches are equivalent while `df[0].equals(df[1].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True))` is 1.5x slower.